# Match keyword and extract line

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textarea where the user will enter multi-line input text and I want to go through it line by line and looking for specific keywords. Once the keyword is found, I want to extract from that keyword until the end of the line (i.e. new line reached).

I have the following code but it only extracts Sender: as output when the alert is executed. I am not really familiar with JavaScript so would really appreciate a better elegant approach than this.

```
function processFunction() {
    var lines = document.getElementById("textarea").value.split('\n');
    for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
        extractSenderIP(lines[i]);
    }
}

function extractSenderIP(someText) {

  var re = new RegExp( "Sender:", "g" );
  var result = re.exec(someText);
  alert(result);
}
```

Comment: To sum up, you are trying to extract some keywords from the textarea? For instance, if the keywords is simple, and your textarea is "this is simple, and simple to", then it will extract two simple's?

Comment: @orabis If I understand OP correctly that would extract only *"simple, and simple to"* because it's on a single line.

Comment: E.g. Line 1 = "Sender: whatever@gmail.com" and Line 2 = "Recipient: whoever@yahoo.com". I want to have a list of predefined keywords such in this example would include Sender and Recipient, and when scanning the lines of the input, if these are present, then it would extract the whole line e.g. Sender: whatever@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is only looking for the word "Sender:". You would need to tell it to find Sender: followed by anything to the next new line char:

```
 var re = new RegExp( "Sender:.*\n", "g" );
```

At that point, you dont really even need to iterate around lines. The global regex should find all instances and return them in a collection.

Comment: `\n` isn't actually needed since `.*` matches any character except newline character.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) by newline `split('\n')`, you can check in your loop if your keyword matches and then get the line like this:

`Sender:.*`

- Match `Sender:`
- Match any character zero or more times `.*`

As an example:

```js
function processFunction() {
    var lines = document.getElementById("textarea").value.split('\n');
    for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
        extractSenderIP(lines[i]);
    }
}

function extractSenderIP(someText) {
    var re = new RegExp("Sender:.*", "g" );
    var result = re.exec(someText);
    if (result && result[0]) {
        console.log(result[0]);
    }
}

processFunction();
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textarea">
Sender:test1
Sender:test1 Sender:test2
Sender: test2
test3</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

`re.exec` returns an object with an `index` attribute, so you could do something like this:

```
result = re.exec(someText);
alert(someText.substring(result.index))
```